# How to enable binning of data in Highcharts (x-range plots) for large data set.(billion points)

Tags: javascript, plot, highcharts, visualization

I have this data which I am trying to visualise in xrange plots. The analysis for the data is done using python and I am plotting in Highcharts. But because of obvious browser memory issues, it cannot plot more than 15-20k points. and my target is to plot atleast a few billion data points. Can anyone guide me to a way as how to enable binning of the data so I can remove overlaps/unnecessary points  in the normal view and make them visible in higher zoom-in levels? I have shortened the data here so it works in the browser.
(See the name col in jsfiddle.)

https://jsfiddle.net/v8yp9nqx/

```
  Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'xrange',
    zoomType: 'x'
},
title: {
    text: 'Highcharts X-range'
},
xAxis: {
    type: 'int'
},
yAxis: {
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    categories: ['Name']
},
series: [{
    turboThreshold:5000000,
    name: 'First',
    // pointPadding: 0,
    // groupPadding: 0,
    borderColor: 'black',
    pointWidth: 10,
    minPointLength: 10,
    data: [
```

Comment: well, obviously you should not try to draw all billion points at once ))), or try to keep them in a memory, try to read more about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_loading

Comment: yes, I totally agree to it, but I need to remove overlapping regions and I am unsure how to approach it. the output should look similar to how we see it now, that means keeping the extreme points of segments at respective zoom levels..

Comment: your question then have no nothing in common with highcharts. You need to update data dynamically, have you perform lazy loading, or developed some criteria of what data should be fetched, when and how?
from the fiddle you've posted you need only 2 points, because result is a strait line, so if you need some algorithm for lazy loading - provide a data, if you have one, provide realization, and explain what is not ok for you

Comment: no, right now it is just all the data. and I did read about lazy loading at https://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/lazy-loading  but as I said, I am unsure how to use this, as right now, all the data is exposed by the API in the required format.

Comment: Although, I think I have an idea now on how to proceed. I need to manage things on the server side and expose them based on the distance between consecutive points. Thanks for your direction of thinking.

Comment: exactly, if you have a closer look at the high-charts example http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/ you'll see that that's what it does. each time you change time-period it sends requests to the server (start-end dates) and then server decides what data to send.